# opening href by touch is not working for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created some social icons using  tag. To open the particular social icon ,i can either touch it or click it . It is working fine for desktop screen and in  my ipad. Whereas it is not working when i tried to open the same link with touch in mobile device. Does anyone experienced this problem? if so, how to solve that?

Comment: we're going to need to see your code to help :)

Comment: I'd suggest you add further information: web browser used on the mobile device, code snippet which tries to achieve what you want, etc.

Comment: There should be something overlapping your button on mobile devices. Check for it.

Comment: what event listeners are assigned to your "buttons"?